# Best way to write the CYPHER query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been trying my simple CYPHER to reduce the db hit.

```
PROFILE MATCH (origin:CS_LOCATION), (destination:CS_LOCATION)
WHERE origin.location_id in[635] AND destination.location_id in[1104642] 
RETURN origin, destination;
```

```
-------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| Operator          | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Cache H/M | Identifiers         | Other                     |
+-------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| +ProduceResults   |            625 |    1 |       0 |       0/0 | destination, origin |                           |
| |                 +----------------+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| +CartesianProduct |            625 |    1 |       0 |       0/0 | destination, origin |                           |
| |\                +----------------+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| | +NodeIndexSeek  |             25 |    1 |       2 |       0/0 | destination         | :CS_LOCATION(location_id) |
| |                 +----------------+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeek    |             25 |    1 |       2 |       0/0 | origin              | :CS_LOCATION(location_id) |
+-------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------------+
```

Here i see CS_LOCATION Referenced twice and i see it performed a DB hit 2 times .Is there anyway i can rewrite the CYPHER to make the 2nd reference of CS_LOCATION read it from cache ?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: profile MATCH (origin:CS_LOCATION), (destination:CS_LOCATION)WHERE origin.location_id in[635] and destination.location_id in[1104642] return  origin, destination

Comment: CYPHER is not SQL.

Comment: The 2nd reference seems to be accessing different nodes, assuming the `location_id` is unique. So caching may not be what you want. Try splitting this into two queries and see what you get. `PROFILE MATCH (origin:CS_LOCATION)
WHERE origin.location_id in[635] RETURN origin` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is not reasonable to expect that an arbitrary second node would be in the cache after getting a different first node.

*Aside: your query actually performs a total of 4 DB hits.*